# Is there only one way to implement a bubble sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I was trying to implement my own bubble sort algorithm without looking at any pseudo-code online, but now that I've successfully done it, mine code looks really different from the examples I see online. They all involve dealing with a swapped variable that is either true or false. My implementation does not include that at all, so did I NOT make a bubble sort?

Here is an example I see online:

```
for i = 1:n,
swapped = false
for j = n:i+1, 
    if a[j] < a[j-1], 
        swap a[j,j-1]
        swapped = true
→ invariant: a[1..i] in final position
break if not swapped
```

end

Here is my implementation of it:

```
void BubbleSort(int* a, int size)
{
    while (!arraySorted(a, size))
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < (size-1))
        {
            if (a[i] < a[i+1])
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                int tmp = 0;
                tmp = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i];
                a[i] = tmp;
                i++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does the same job, but does it do it any differently?

Comment: Your version is twice as slow because `arraySorted` costs as much as an iteration of the loop body.

Comment: @Raymond Chen So basically the swapped variable is absolutely essential?

Comment: Did you understand the premise behind the pair of indexes walking up the sequence? On *any* given pass, if no swaps happen for any given adjacent elements, the sequence is by-definition sorted, and you're done. Detecting that a swap happened a, thus another pass is needed is the fundamental reason for that flag.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right. So I'm just making it iterate needlessly when the sorting process itself should determine if it is sorted?

Comment: Yes, evaluating that flag is done once per pass, which will beat the pants off scanning the sequence one per pass.

Answer (score 0):

As some people noted, your version without the flag works, but is needlessly slow.

However, if you take the original version and just throw away the flag (together with the `break`), it will still work. It's easy to see from the invariant that you conveniently posted.

The version without the break has roughly the same worst-case performance as with the break (worst case is for an array sorted in reverse order). It's better than the original one if you want an algorithm that is guaranteed to finish in a pre-defined time.

Wikipedia describes [another idea for optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) of the bubble-sort, which includes throwing away the `break`.